# SQL Derby: GROUP BY not selected id

Tags: java, sql, select, derby

I am using [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).
I have a table with two columns X and Y.
I want to select column X but group by column Y.
This means I want to show only ONE X value for each row with the first Y value to it.

How can I do this?

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    x INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
    y INTEGER  NOT NULL )

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,1) ,(1,2) ,(1,3) ,(2 ,3),(3,3)

SELECT y FROM test GROUP BY x -- does not work
```

i want all y values with no duplicate

**Raw Data**

```
X    Y
--   --
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    3
3    3
```

The results should be:

```
X    Y
--   --
1    1
1    2
2    3
```

Comment: what aggregate did you want on that `x` - the MAX, MIN ?

Comment: What is the “first Y value” in your case?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Posting some example data and your desired output for this data would really help.

Comment: can you fill in the details of what the results should look like?

Comment: how does 2 get picked for X when the Y is 3?

Answer (score 4):

You've got to [aggregate](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) `x` in some fashion:

```
SELECT   Y,
         MAX(X) AS Max_X,
         AVG(X) AS Avg_X

FROM     myTable
GROUP BY Y
ORDER BY Y
```

Minimum, Maximum, Average, First, Last, etc.

If you don't care which `x` you get, perhaps just choose the first or last:

```
SELECT   Y,
         First(X) AS X,
FROM     myTable
GROUP BY Y
```

Comment: i dont need any aggregate method 
i need the values with no duplicated

Answer (score 0):

You must specify which `X` you want.

```
select
  min(X) X
from
  table
group by
  Y
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with Derby, but try a sub-query like:

```
SELECT X
FROM table
WHERE Y in (SELECT MIN(Y) FROM table)
```

Here `SELECT MIN(Y) FROM table` is to select the value for Y (i.e. your “first Y value”, here: the minimum of Y).